# Where did I login when one pods have multipe containers, kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have one deployment which has two containers.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ol000dep
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ol000kube
  replicas : 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ol000kube
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django
          image: django:local
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8011
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:local
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

This makes two replicad pods, and on my understanding, each pod has two containers.

```
kubectl get pods      
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ol000dep-bc96bfc98-r9lrj   1/1     Running   0          21m
ol000dep-bc96bfc98-t6flw   1/1     Running   0          21m
```

Now I can login

```
kubectl exec -it ol000dep-bc96bfc98-r9lrj  /bin/bash
```

Then, I wonder,

Is this login in a Pod not a Container??

If so ,how can I select the container I want to login?

Comment: A pretty common setup is to have only one container per pod.  If you update your Python code, do you also need to redeploy the Nginx proxies?  Do you need exactly the same number of proxies as application servers, or does it make sense to scale these separately?  I might break this into two separate Deployments with matching Services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. Even though the yaml you provided is incorrect (`.spec.containers` map key must be **unique**), k8s seems to be fine with that.

In your case the pod is started with **only** the second container (name: nginx) in it though.

> Is this login in a Pod not a Container??

**Container.**

So, with  `kubectl exec -it ol000dep-bc96bfc98-r9lrj /bin/bash`, you login/exec into the nginx container.

After correcting the yaml, two containers would be started in the pod and you can log into the desired container via its name (e.g. `name: django`) using the `-c / --container` parameter.

```yaml
...
      containers:
        - name: django
          image: django:local
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8011
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:local
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

login:

```
kubectl exec -it POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME -- /bin/bash
```

Note that if you do not specify the name of the container (by omitting `-c CONTAINER_NAME`), you will login into the first defined container by default (in your case `django`).

Comment: Ah, you are right. Only one contaner works in the pod, I fixed that mistake and also can login each container with `-c container_name`. thank you very much !!!!!

Comment: And when there are two containers works propely and login without `-c`, it says `Defaulted container "django" out of: django, nginx` message clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
kubectl exec -it ol000dep-bc96bfc98-r9lrj  --container django(nginx)  -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can select the container with `--container`